# Iterate over area elements with $.each() or for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, area, each

Is there a way to avoid repeating code when iterating over area elements with Jquery? or an easier way with plain javascript? A snippet of the HTML:

```
    <img id="img1" src="image.png" width="400px" height="400px" usemap="#area_click"title="click to shade different areas" />
<map name="area_click">
    <area href="" shape="poly" coords="33,149,53,151,49,183,45,205,27,197,29,171" alt="area1" >
    <area href="" shape="poly" coords="157,148,161,168,161,201,143,204,139,180,137,152" alt="area2" >
    <area href="" shape="poly" coords="51,144,55,126,57,114,41,88,32,112,32,140" alt="area3" >//...35 more areas follow...
</map>
```

I have tried...

1. Create array from map children.

   ```
   var kids=$("map[name*='area_click']").children();
   ```
2. Loop through the array.

   ```
   for (var k=0;k<kids.length;k++){
   kids[k].click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       $("#" + AreaArray[k]).fadeToggle(500).fadeTo(300,opacityArray[k]);});}
   ```

I thought I was missing something about the array-like object created by children().
So I tried...

1.Create array from map children. Then use eq() to grab references to the DOM elements in the array.

```
    var kids=$("map[name*='area_click']").children();
    var kidsArray = kids.eq();
```

2.Loop through the array.

```
    for (var k=0;k<kidsArray.length;k++){
    kidsArray[k].click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#" + AreaArray[k]).fadeToggle(500).fadeTo(300,opacityArray[k]);});}
```

Also tried using $.each and find() instead of children(). But it seems $.each() cannot digest area elements. The following generates a type error in the jquery.min script in the Firebug console.

TypeError: t is undefined
...nction(e){var t,n="",r=0,i=e.nodeType;if(i){if(1===i||9===i||11===i){if("string"...

```
    var kids=$("map[name*='area_click']").find("area");
var k=0;
    $.each(kids.eq(k)).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#" + areaArray[k]).fadeToggle(500).fadeTo(300,opacityArray[k]);
        k++;
    });
```

I'm sure I am doing something wrong in trying to pass a reference to the array to the for loop or $.each(), I just don't know what. Any help? Or am I going about the whole thing backwards?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: You can add a class to each area element and do $(.class).each(function () {...});

Comment: `$.each(kids.eq(k)).click` makes no sense. Your first attempt, you should use .each rather than a for loop so that you don't lose the jquery wrapper, and thus can add a click handler with .click.

Comment: thank you for the use of closures link Arun, will study and attempt to apply.

Comment: I didn't think area elements accepted class attributes, but will try, thank you q2liu.

Comment: Please don't update your question in that way. I have rolled it back. A comment here or on the answer, which you've done, is sufficient if you want to do more than the Accept. You might even want to come back and Upvote Arun's answer when you have sufficient reputation.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I'll know the etiquette for next time, sorry to have troubled you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with the closure variable `k`, try

```
kids.each(function (k) {
    $(this).click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#" + AreaArray[k]).fadeToggle(500).fadeTo(300, opacityArray[k]);
    });
})
```

---

Or

```
kids.click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var k = kids.index(this)
    $("#" + AreaArray[k]).fadeToggle(500).fadeTo(300, opacityArray[k]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying this Arun!!! It works, you're _great_! Now I have some closure on this issue. Thank you for saving me lots of bytes.